# Portable HD Failure

Tags: external-hard-drive

While performing a disk defrag on a portable samsung 2TB NTFS Hard disk, I was on a boat the power just went out. Frying the BIOS battery of the laptop and causing a great deal of files on the HD to just become invalid.

Out of the  1,81 total space the HD gives me, I can only see 838gb, so, given that I have 181gb of free space, it therefore means that 791gb worth of files have become invalid.

I can still see them, all the folders with those 791gb are still visible, but they no longer show the regular folder icon their size is 0kb and their type is now File instead of File Folder.

My antivirus software can still access each and every file inside those folders and a HD Tune software has found no errors.

Am I right to assume that if I just have it run another disk defrag will all my folder go back to normal (accessible)?

Comment: Your HD is most likely corrupt. I highly doubt doing another disk defrag will do anything other than corrupting more data. Your best option would be to reformat the disk and restore from a backup.

Comment: thank for that mate. Although I was rather hoping for more cheerful news, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can take a try with entering in a command window `CHKDSK /R x:` (x = whatever your drive letter is). It's free, and it has a pretty good chance to fix the issues (it might run an hour or longer, don't worry). With only a power-out, that should fix it.

However, it could be that the damage is more severe (if there was more tahn a simple outage), and then only a professional company could really help you, for significant money.

I recommend you try *only* the CHKDSK as described above, and if it doesn't work, make up your mind if you want to spend a lot of money, or live with the content gone.

Comment: MFT BITMAP Attribute is incorrect
and
Volume Bitmap is incorrect

CMD than suggested I ran a scan, so I did, after about 3min it was over with, ,problem still persists

Still cannot comprehend why the antivirus and HD Scan can clearly ready all the `gone` files though